# Colorbox with complex content in Beamer

Tags: beamer, color, boxes

Here is my problem. I try to create a macro that displays a colored background for "any" kind of elements in a beamer presentation.

Here is what I did :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{philex}
\usetheme{Berkeley}


\definecolor{boxalertcolor}{RGB}{165,165,221}
\def \boxalert#1#2{\alt<#1>{\colorbox{boxalertcolor}{\begin{minipage}{.97\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}}}{\hbox{\begin{minipage}{.97\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
    \begin{exampleblock}{What is the rule behind these sentences ?} 
        \boxalert{2,4}{
         \lb{chien}{
        \lba{chienJuste}{The dog runs.}
        \lbz{chienFaux}{* The run dog.}}}   
    \boxalert{3-4}{\lb{oiseau}{
        \lba{oiseauJuste}{I saw a bird.}
        \lbz{oiseauFaux}{* I a saw bird.}}}                                             
 \end{exampleblock}
     \pause
 \begin{block}{Possible rules}   
 \boxalert{2}{
    \begin{description}[$R_1$]       
        \item[$R_1$]The word \textit{the} must appear just before \textit{dog} to constitute a nominal phrase.
    \end{description}}
    \pause
    \boxalert{3}{
    \begin{description}[$R_1$]
         \item[$R_2$]The word \textit{a} must appear just before \textit{bird} to constitute a nominal phrase.
    \end{description}}
    \pause
    \boxalert{4}{
    \begin{description}[$R_1$]
         \item[$R_i$]The deteminant must appear just before the name to constitute a nominal phrase.
     \end{description}}
 \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now my problem is that spaces are not the same between colored and not colored versions of the content. I know that it is due to the `\fboxsep` that goes with the `\colorbox`. And I don't want to remove it for the colored version.

So the question is: **how can I properly add the missing spaces in the *non-colored* version, in a way that the text of both versions perfectly overlap?**

So I'm asking for an improvement of the macro I have. But if someone knows a better/easyer/nicer way to do the same with a totally different code, I would be perfectly happy to replace my macro.

Thanks a lot!
BH

EDIT : If I replace my macro `\boxalert`by the following code, I'm almost done :

```
\def \boxalert#1#2{\alt<#1>{\colorbox{boxalertcolor}{\begin{minipage}{.97\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}}}{\vspace{\fboxsep}\hspace{\fboxsep}\begin{minipage}{.97\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}}}
```

But during the transition between slides 2 and 3, there's a space that moves the boxes, and I have no idea where it comes from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `\fbox` where you remove the rules:

```
\definecolor{boxalertcolor}{RGB}{165,165,221}
\newcommand\boxalert[2]{%
  \alt<#1>%
    {\colorbox{boxalertcolor}{\begin{minipage}{.97\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}}}%
    {\begingroup\fboxrule=0pt\fbox{\begin{minipage}{.97\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}}\endgroup}%
}
```

This will add the same padding as `\colorbox` with a transparent background.

Comment: Brilliant! That's perfect, thank you very much!
Just an additional question: To avoid my colorbox to go beyond the main block, I set the lenght of the minipage with `.97\textwidth`. It's a bot approximative. Is there a better way to set this?

Comment: @BonyHoax `\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep` gives a symmetric placement; what's the difference between `\textwidth` and the width of a block I don't know and it's probably hidden in the style.